# Alternative to Index + Seek on Access/DAO Using SQL Server/ADO

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ado, dao

I'm converting an Excel app from a local MS Access backend (with DAO) to SQL Server running on Azure (with ADO).

A common task I perform with DAO is the index + seek method to scan a large amount of input rows (~10,000, and using multi field indexes), check for matching records in the database, and update or add new records as required. The NoMatch property of the Seek method works very nicely when deciding to add or update.

This seems like it should be pretty simple with SQL Server, but I can't seem to find a good solution that lets me check for matches, add or update, and use multi column indexes.

Downloading the table to memory then doing a batch update would be fine, but ADO's Find method doesn't seem as good as index + seek, and it can't use multi columns. Connecting to SQL Server with an ADO provider that supports index seek would also work (Jet 4.0?) but I can't find examples of that either.

Am I missing something obvious? What is the best way to check and add or update large number of rows to SQL Server? Thanks

Edit:
Here's a simple example of the operation I'm doing currently in Access/DAO:

```vb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TableName", dbOpenTable)
    With rs
        .Index = "MultiFieldIndex"

        'Loop through the input data
        For i = 1 To 10000
            .Seek "=", Criteria1, Criteria2

            If Not .NoMatch Then
                'Found a match, just update specific fields
                !Field1 = a
                !Field2 = b

                Else
                'No match found, add a new record then populate
                .AddNew
                !Field3 = c
                !Field4 = d

            End If

            .Update
        Next i
    End With
```

Whats the best way to do something like this only with SQL? I'd still probably start with loading a disconnected recordset of the full target table, but not sure how to update a few thousand records when I don't know if I'll need to update or add new, or the values of the input criteria. How do I find the rows I need to update/check without index + seek?

OR can I create a temp table in memory with only the input data then somehow just 'merge' that table to the database and the db will figure out how to update or add?

I feel like this should be a pretty basic procedure, but maybe I'm just missing some fundamental SQL concept?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Hi Jayme, welcome to StackOverflow! could you please add a sample of your code in DAO? No need to go too explicit with the DAO code, even a simple sample such as "select * from table; update table set column = 7 where key= 2" would be good enough for us to help you how to convert code from DAO to ADO. Thanks!

Comment: _"What is the best way to check and add or update large number of rows to SQL Server?"_ an `UPDATE` followed by an `INSERT` operation within a single transaction would be my preferred method.

Comment: 10K is no data at all and probably fits in a CPU's cache. Even in Access retrieving all data in memory is slow and won't work if two or more users were accessing the same table, or if one user wants to update/insert multiple rows. A faster way even in Access would be to use *SQL* to modify data, not operations like Find. Indexing is something that's defined in advance too. You can define multiple indexes with multiple columns. The database will update them automatically when the data is modified.

Comment: BTW DAO was abandoned somewhere in 1998 I think - I caught that transition. Even Access works with ADO since 2000. A single UPDATE WHERE is far faster than seeking to an item, modifying it, storing and repeating inside a cursor. In a multiuser environment the result will be constant blocking and concurrency conflicts. The reason you don't find any docs is because that way of working was abandoned 20 years ago. Any relevant docs would be from that period and probably haven't survived - back then, the docs came in 4 CDs with the entire MSDN library, which later became 1 DVD.

Comment: The typical way of working with ADO is to load a [**disconnected** recordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/disconnecting-and-reconnecting-the-recordset?view=sql-server-2017) (that means you actually close the connection), make any modifications to it, and then connect back to the database and apply any changes. Optimistic concurrency is used to catch conflicts, not transactions. That's several orders of magnitude more scalable and faster than transactions and cursors - think thousands of times faster.

Comment: Searching for `ado disconnected recordset` I found that the current online documentation covers this adequately in [Batch Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/batch-mode?view=sql-server-2017). Have you checked this?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes the batch mode stuff will work, that solves part of it for sure. But do you know of an easy way to find all the thousands of records I need to update without seeking? Surely I'm not the first person to need to find and update lots of records at once...

Comment: @HilaDG I added the sample code, does this give you any ideas? thanks!

Comment: @gvee I added some sample code, do you have a link to an example where update/insert would work in this situation? thanks!

Comment: @JaymeGordon write a SQL query. Not Find, not Seek. Not Index, which you don't need. Those methods were obsolete 20 years ago. While they remained useful for *file based databases ONLY*, they have no meaning in an RDBMS. You aren't alone any more, there will be hundreds of other users trying to access the same tables

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to write an SQL query

`create procedure dbo.prc_TableNameUpdIns (@parm1 int, @parm2 int)
AS
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * from MyTable WHERE A = @parm1 AND B = @parm2)
   UPDATE ...
   ELSE
   INSERT....`

GO

(you *could* use merge but I advise against it)

And you call the SP by creating an AdoConnection (in VBA)

   `dim myAdoConnection as ADOConnection`

dim X as Integer, Y as Integer
   X = 7
   Y = 8

'SET the myAdoConnection
   'Calling the proc
   myAdoConnection.prc_TableNameUpdIns X, Y

Processing as much code as possible in the SQL is much preferable. The only time you need to do this type of ADO manipulation is when you need to update the form *only* and not necessarily the database itself.

About [ADO connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/activex-data-objects/create-an-ado-connection-string)
And research the subject some more, this is only a pointer